# Images Not Laying Flush With Each Other

Tags: html, css

I have some images on a page that I want to turn into links for projects that I have done but they don't seem to want to lay flush with one another.

```
.projectimage {
    transition: 2s;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:25%;
}

.projectimage:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px) contrast(1.5) grayscale(0.4) sepia(0.2);
}
```

And here's the HTML.

```
<a href="#">
<img class="projectimage" src="../images/projects/texmex.png"  width="25%"  /></a>
```

I took all the margins and padding out so I have no idea on why it has spacing...

Comment: Can you re-create the issue in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: a jsfiddle will help.

Comment: Looking at the above, probably it's whitespace in the markup combined with inline elements. If so, easy fix - make the links block, and float them.

Comment: line breaks in markup count as whitespace in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display: block` to your images. They are default to `display: inline` causing them to have an extra few px around them.

If you comment out the `display: block`, you can see the extra px at the bottom of the top images (even with `display: block` on the a tags).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eZBEt/1/)**

```
a {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of inline-block element surrounding whitespace. See the followinjg for an explanation and a number of solutions.

http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/